# I get a failed to load script error when i am trying to host my React vite application in nginx server

Tags: reactjs, docker, nginx, vite

I have a React+ts which is built during vite bundler. Now i am trying to host the application in a docker image using nginx web server. The site is getting loaded because i see my application name on chrome tab. But i get an error in the console.

```
Failed to load module script: Expected a JavaScript module script but the server responded with a MIME type of "text/html". Strict MIME type checking is enforced for module scripts per HTML spec.
```

Here is my vite.config.ts

```
import { defineConfig, loadEnv } from "vite";
import react from "@vitejs/plugin-react-swc";

// https://vitejs.dev/config/
export default defineConfig(({ mode }) => {
  const env = loadEnv(mode, process.cwd());

  return {
    base: env.VITE_APP_BASE_PATH,
    plugins: [react()],
    server: {
      port: 3000,
      https: {
        cert: "./certs/certificate.pem",
        key: "./certs/key.pem",
      },
    },
  };
});
```

nginx/nginx.conf

```
server {
    listen 8080;
    server_name localhost;
    include mime.types;
    types {
        application/javascript js mjs;
    }
    
    location / {
        root /usr/share/nginx/html;
        index index.html;
        try_files $uri $uri/ /queryhubadmin/index.html;
    }

    location /api/ {
        proxy_pass https://localhost:8443;
    }
}
```

This is my Dockerfile

```
FROM node:18 as build

WORKDIR /app

COPY AdminUI/package*.json .

RUN npm i

COPY AdminUI .

RUN ls

RUN npm run build

FROM nginx:alpine

COPY --from=build /app/dist /usr/share/nginx/html

RUN ls  

COPY AdminUI/nginx/nginx.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf

CMD ["nginx", "-g", "daemon off;"]
```